# Storing list of one enum to one column in database with Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I need to **store all items from one list of ONE specific enum to ONE column in database utilizing Hibernate. Items in column should be divided by comma.** So result in column should be for instance: WELCOME, PREVIOUS

This is my UserEntity

```
@Column
@Enumerated
@ElementCollection(targetClass = ViewedItem.class)
private List<ViewedItem> viewedItems;
```

```
enum ViewedItem {
   WELCOME,
   PREVIOUS
}
```

Problem with this solution is that it requires a new table in database with enum *ViewedItem*. This enum must be used only in application not in database. I cannot also store it as simple string in class *UserEntity*.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Don't do this. Storing values as CSV is very bad db design

Comment: @Jens , it is requirement from my management, so it must be done this way. Otherwise I would do it differently.

Comment: Don't use an ElemenetCollection/Enumerated annotations and instead use @Converter with an implementation of AttributeConverter<List<ViewedItem>, String> to perform the conversions from Lists to String data how ever you might want.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can use the json-binary data-type. And with Json-Binary you can store (typically small) collections of Enums or Key/Value pairs very easily.

Please find snippets below and change Map to a `List<ViewedItem>`

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
id int8 NOT NULL,
namesOfCitiesInDifferentLanguages jsonb NULL)
```

JPA:

```
public class myTable {
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private Map<Language, String> namesOfCitiesInDifferentLanguages ;
}
```

Column-value:

```
{"EN": "Antwerp", "FR": "Anvers", "NL": "Antwerpen"}
```